# Connection reset error with Git Credential Manager OSX

Tags: git, azure-devops

We have Azure DevOps GIT repos. I have been using git successfully with them for a LONG time. All of a sudden, today, I cannot push changes. The Git Credential Manager is giving me Connection Reset errors after I successfully go to the website and put in the access code. I have tried updating JAVA, GIT, and the Git Credential Manager on my MacBook Pro to no avail. Google searches turn up very little. Any idea how I can get git working again? This is the error it is throwing:

> Fatal: java.lang.Error encountered.  Details:
>   java.net.SocketException: Connection reset fatal: credential helper
>   '!/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java
>   -Ddebug=false -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true -jar /usr/local/Cellar/git-credential-manager/2.0.4/libexec/git-credential-manager-2.0.4.jar'
>   told us to quit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out what was going on. Azure DevOps was throwing a GIT error. Instead of displaying the GIT error in the command line, it would just swallow the error and terminate the connection. I figured this out by putting the Git Credential Manager into debug mode. Then it should me the error which was happening and terminated the connection. GCM and Azure DevOps should not swallow errors, that's just poor design. I posted an issue on the GCM site.

Answer (score 0):

`JAVA_HOME` might have been changed. because path `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java` appears to be messed up - that should possibly be `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/bin/java` instead.

and if you've updated Java, you might (also) have to exclude it (adjust the path as required):

```
[credential] helper = !/usr/lib/jvm/java-10-jdk/bin/java --add-modules java.xml.bind -Ddebug=false -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true -jar /usr/share/java/git-credential-manager-2.0.4.jar
```

notice the difference: `--add-modules java.xml.bind`

`-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` might be required (to disable IP v6).

the `JVM` would also support verbose output with `-verbose:class`

... because "connection reset" can have many reasons.